# Typescript mapped generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to get TS generics to map to a new object.  In short, I'm trying to convert:

```
{ 
  key: { handler: () => string },
  key2: { hander: () => number },
}
```

to:

```
{ key: string, key2: number }
```

full example:

```
type programOption = {
  validator: () => unknown
}

type programConfig<T extends {[key: string]: programOption} = {}> = {
  options: T,
  handler: (data: mapProgramConfig<T>) => void,
}

type mapProgramConfig<T extends {[key: string]: programOption}> = {
  [K in keyof T]: ReturnType<programOption['validator']>
}

type mapProgramConfigHardcoded<T> = {
  fruit: string,
  animal: number
}

class Program {
  constructor (config: programConfig) {}
}

const foo = new Program({
  options: {
    'fruit': { validator: () => 'asdf' },
    'animal': { validator: () => 42 },
  },
  handler: ({fruit, animal, thing}) => {

  },
});
```

Exactly what I'm trying to do can be seen if you replace `mapProgramConfig` with `mapProgramConfigHardcoded` in the `programConfig` type, but I can't seem to make it work in the generic case.

[ts playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBGBOD2BzWBDAtgeTMAlvAdlALxQDeAUFFAG4oA2OAJisPLAFxQAUAlMQHxQArvgDW+eAHd85AL7lyoSDATJ0AYQIAzHIgA8AFSgQAHsAj5GAZzIBtURBCcrwWDnyIAupzhJUmbDx8WWIyWUESCip4QIIrTgMAGkooAAsUSzoIDm5mYBRONBQwAAVVf018HX0Dfj4iQWp4JmT5RXBoItLyjW1dQ2MzC2s7BycoFzcPbxU-dCxcAnDQqKhbAGkodygx+C0oAxmAJQhgIVh8Aw69XzUAxfxbAHJaBjy2J89+OQUlTuKynM0JVqgAJFCwRgAY3gjAgjEMETIKS0sCEOGAzlc7kQySoGRwRTonHwQjQACNsj9yFC6CgrDZAXdkVQYfhJkIoaxYNw2dUfD1gX1EHxSPI2myXFAtPB4KF8BBJFAmf4uKsYg94iyqFAnqj0cAnpxSDR6EwWGxOLwBLr6YwtE8oLI8TqngSiUayKa3hactaGlAACwAJidLudKXSmWyVtI+oxiSg7voieAqRxsnqggoKQjmYA3AogA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it like this

```
type programConfig<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  options: {
    [K in keyof T]: {
      validator: () => T[K]
    }
  },
  handler: (data: T) => void, // ??? should be {optionKey: inferred return type}
}

class Program<T extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>> {
  constructor(config: programConfig<T>) { }
}
```

and when you call it the generic will be inferred only with the necessary data (the key and the data type)

```js
const foo: Program<{
    fruit: string;
    animal: number;
}>
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBGBOD2BzWBDAtgYXgOwGYEtEAeAFSggA9gJsATAZygCUIBjeWWo+4WfbRABooKbCAB84qAF4oAbwBQUKPDDB8OegC55S5VADaAaSj8oAawgh4uKCQC6Oxfv0A3FABt8tFMA46ACgBKGSkSY3s9ZQBfPWjBPQALUVoPCFhAn2AUHRIQ6SlXeG9hAHpSqAB+aqh6RPgAVw9aKAAjaDlVdRwjKx1+XHTYCBbh4AbYbChQSFjYhVYPFHpGAAUEZHRScioaBmY2Di4ePgFhUQkZA-ZObl5+IRExSV1ldmwThtY-WAD3gkQOjgSFQmBwANI4hCcigcwUC00wCguHg8Cu2AgAHcoOsQegAs4VGoNB8nFEoAByXCwBr4YAUpxQdxeLL+KDBUKU5a0XAU2EJFwU0T4NCeBnyJmeby+NkcgpQAAsACZ+XEBVBknQ0hl2TDqbTgOdsCLPMJgIkHrD8lJCW9NPA0gA6DxIAL6ulGk0eIJqhTRIIAbgUQA)

Comment: nice solution! a bit simplier than mine

Answer (score 3):

Consider this solution:

```js
type ProgramOption<T> = {
  validator?: () => T
}


type Convert<Obj extends Record<string, ProgramOption<any>>> = {
  [Prop in keyof Obj]: Obj[Prop]['validator'] extends () => infer Return ? Return : never
}
const program = <
  Keys extends PropertyKey,
  ValidatorValues extends string | number,
  Options extends Record<Keys, ProgramOption<ValidatorValues>>,
  Handler extends (data: Convert<Options>) => void,
  >(data: { options: Options, handler: Handler },) => {
  return data
}

const foo = program({
  options: {
    'fruit': { validator: () => 'string' },
    'animal': { validator: () => 42 },
  },
  handler: (obj) => {
    obj.animal // 42
    obj.fruit // 'string'
  }
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewOZwIYFsDyZgEsEB2APACoB8UAvFAN4BQUUAbqgDa4AmqwCcA-AC4oACgCUVCiToBfOnNCQoAYUJMIcYEUwAjAFZQIAD2AQCHAM5QAShADGvDkXPA4uAkgA0sRCgzY8hESoBCBkYVS0DFAA2vAIYFBuUADWECAIAGZQOroAukI5sYhgudEA5CzsXDxwZbkGxqYWIuKUFG4Z6tYQwACucARQfN19A1BCBBBqcDJ09gTOUGA%20aOgRRFEA0mmWRiZmlnGQGiDbIB5RAGpsnNy816y9ELuNB1DOru5QAD5QBL3obTqC6Mfz4BYNfbNGz2OCOM7mLxxXxYHDgogPW41B5PcxhEFQAASwQ4rC6eyalmE1VQQhUBGmmjBhDxrQoTAQnAJAHpucpCBlcEhIZTaFB4gEFgU0SyvAALElkuBCYlmJVQaQEsjU7i0sUS8HmaWSxFQBVq9QqxVdTVsyKMOA9fqDGmzOYs4BQDIIBARZbIVbCeiMA0soTBxhQMoZOC9XDAMrh5g3aq8IRiCRRj5uJBlDUExhlYK4dBsRNiypYtMtTMAFgATPmopqoubSZaRAg9HaIyG9AA6Yul1hQXlQBtRPu6fsxuOesdlbPuMrNmSiADcQA)

In order to infer `obj` argument in `handler` property you need infer all nested keys and values.

**`Keys`** - refers to `fruit` and `animal` keys of nested object
**`ValidatorValues`** - refers to `Validator` return type
**`Options`** - refers to whole `options` property
**`Handler`** - refers to `handler` accordingly.

I have used `Convert` utility type to iterate through `Options` type and grab all return types of `validator` property

If you are interested in function arguments inference you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

I have used `program` function instead of `Program` class because
`Type parameters cannot appear on a constructor declaration`

Comment: Thanks!  I think this provides what I need to make it work.  Simplifying it and converting it back to the format I need now!

Comment: Thanks!  Works great, I removed the requirement to manually define the return types (`string | number`) and the extra generics seem to be unnecessary: https://tsplay.dev/NBe7nw, but this is exactly what I needed :)

Comment: @Nobody you are welcome. I always trying to add more generic than it is necessary :D

Answer (score 0):

you just need to extend the generic defined on the `programConfig` interface to the `Program` class:

```
class Program<T extends {[key: string]: programOption} = {}> {
  constructor (config: programConfig<T>) {}
}
```

Comment: Almost, but now `fruit` and `animal` are both `unknown`, as defined in `validator: () => unknown`